# Logic quantifiers displayed wrong when using newpxmath

Tags: math-mode, symbols, debugging, math-fonts

When using the package `newpxmath`, the quantifiers `\forall`and `\exists` are displayed as `\hslash` and `\hbar`, respectively.
See the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\begin{document}
$\forall$ and $\exists$ look like $\hslash$ and $\hbar$ 
\end{document}
```

This happens with MacTeX 2019 and the most recent updates installed (according to TeX Live Utility); it did not happen with a fresh install of MacTeX 2019 before updating the packages, and does not happen with MacTeX 2017. I tested this with `pdflatex` and  `latex`.

As far as I can tell, a workaround is declaring both quantifiers explicitly by adding the following to the preamble:

```latex
\DeclareMathSymbol{\exists}{\mathord}{symbols}{57}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\forall}{\mathord}{symbols}{56}
```

How can I find out whether the problem is with my system or one of the packages? And if it is the latter, whom should one report this to?

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour with version `2019/10/02 v1.401` of `newpxmath`, this looks very much like a bug. The e-mail for bug reports is mentioned at the end of the readme of the package on CTAN http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/newpx/README

Comment: Thanks for reproducing this! (And for the comment, of course.) I'll file a bug report right after finishing this comment.

Comment: These are not the only symbols to be fixed.

Comment: The fixed version for `\exists` and `\forall` has been released (https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live-commits/2019-October/011145.html). @egreg This were the only symbols that were fixed. If you have a more exhaustive list of more problematic symbols I'm sure the package developer wouldn't mind a heads-up.